# Uploading attachments in ALM

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am Using the below code in my VAPI-XP script to upload my latest file in Test lab. But the attachments are not getting uploaded.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\Services\2017\Test\New folder")
Set recentFile = Nothing

For Each file in folder.Files   
    If UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file.name)) = "XLS" Then      
        If (recentFile is Nothing) Then         
            Set recentFile = file           
        ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then           
            Set recentFile = file           
        End If      
    End If  
Next


TDHelper.UploadAttachment "D:\Services\2017\Test\New folder" & "\" & recentFile.name, CurrentRun
```

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: No. the test case has been passed, but the attachments were not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your folder name. You have to write use two double quotes `""` as such:

```
""D:\Services\2017\Test\New folder""
```